# Techniques in Bending String, Electric Guitar

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, note-bending

When I bend the string, my fingers pressing on the bended string always easily go under the upper string. I think part of the issue is that my strings are quite high, but after fixing the height down a little bit, I still can't make it completely right. And I saw in some tutorial videos one almost presses on two strings and bend them all up, though they actually only ought to bend the lower string. Is that right way to do it?

Comment: How high is your string action? Pushing a finger under a string should be almost impossible on a properly adjusted guitar.

Comment: @Peteris: well, it's about 3mm at 12th fret. It's fine when dealing with 8th fret but slipping  does happen at 12th or higher frets.

Comment: @Tim: Sorry about the confusion, I actually means while bending B string, G string slips over my fingers. And it seems that in the tutorial, one catches B and G strings and bend them up though he wants to play a single note on B string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bend the thin E string, I can't see any other way than that the B and sometimes G string will also follow in the same movement. They are not making a sound since they are not touching the frets. So the tutorial videos are showing the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I think he's saying that the B or G string is slipping over his fingers while bending the high E. But the "upper" and "lower" terms seem very confusing to me.

Comment: @luserdroog: That's how I understood the situation. I interpret the question to be "should adjacent strings be included when bending a single note (sufficiently far)". The answer is yes.

Comment: Ok. I interpreted it as "how to avoid the slipping": a problem I've had myself (and I don't know the answer). But re-reading, he doesn't appear to actually say that.

Comment: @luserdroog: You mean that you lose the grip of the string with the note being bent?

Comment: No, what happens is the adjacent strings get on top of my fingernail and slide over the top of my fingers. My fingertips and the string I'm trying to bend *dive* under the next strings. It's often a sign that my left-hand fingernails are too long, but not always. I can usually overcome it with more practice, but it still happens to me after 20+ years of playing.

Comment: @luserdroog: Sounds like you might start your bends with your fingers too perpendicular to the fretboard. If you try the "thumb over the neck"-technique (á la Hendrix) you will be forced to have the fingers more parallel to the fretboard, and the flesh of your fingertips should catch the other strings.

Comment: I think that's it exactly. In the piece where it keeps happening, though, I'm trying to bend the B-string 4th-fret up to E while the E-string is ringing. So I can't go too horizontal without damping the E-string. Catch-22.

Comment: @luserdroog: Tricky stuff. An alternative could be to bend the G string at the 8th fret down instead, but there might of course be other things preventing that.

Comment: The only time to worry is when the adjacent string goes between the nail and the finger flesh. The Chinese apparently used this as a torture.

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername,@luser droog: Sorry about the confusion, actually I should have broken the question into two parts. Firstly, I have a problem about how to avoid G string sliding over my fingers while bending B string. Moreover, I wonder wether it is right  to catch both both B and G strings and bend them up( not to catch only B string, bend it up, and simultaneously push up G string using the very top of your fingertips) if you only want to play a single note on B string.

Comment: @user10179: To avoid the string sliding over your finger, try to have your left hand thumb on top of the neck instead of behind. Then your fingers will be more parallel to the fretboard, and you should avoid sliding under. The added benefit is that you easily catch the G string with the flesh of your fingertip, without it touching a fret. In this way the G string will make no sound.

Answer (score 0):

First of all adjust the action/height on your electric guitar , this [link](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-adjust-action-electric-guitar-12101595.html) may help you or you can just google it . For your second issue, suppose that you want to bend 8th fret of second string (this note is `G` ) if you `full bend` it (not 1/2) you would hear `A` note (the next note after `G`) . During bending of any note your left hand finger (if you are right handed) maybe touches the upper string or maybe not ! you should bend the note to reach the frequency of the next note , that's the point. Because you didn't picked upper string (in our example third string=`G`) it shouldn't make any noise. hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

Don't think it is really an issue. Sometimes adjacent strings are pushed too, so they bend as well, silently. Sometimes the adjacent string goes over the bent string as its pushed underneath.Does it really matter? If people like Hendrix had spent (wasted) their time thinking 'is this the correct way to do it' we'd still be in the dark ages.Whatever works best for the individual is best.No-one should have the right to state on the internet: 'This is the proper way to do this'when trying to show the world how THEY do it. But the internet seems to be the new Bible.

Comment: If the nail slips under the string, it might cause unwanted noise when the finger is retracted. That could be a reason for avoiding it. I have never seen anyone use this technique successfully, so in my experience that is not the way to do it.

Comment: I do it whenever necessary. It's not a problem. Any technique that can be honed is worthwhile working on. Generally only use it when a big bend is needed.If it doesn't work for you, then you won't use it.My actions are very low, and strings very light, so make your own conclusions.

Comment: You let the B string slide over your finger when you're bending the thin E string? A technique without value is not worth honing, in my mind. I would not recommend anyone to hold their pick with the middle finger either, even if EVH managed to produce great results that way. If someone new to the instrument asks, I think it is valid to recommend the most used approaches. Sliding the string over the finger while bending is not one of those.

Comment: It is not being advocated any more highly than any other technique. I am trying to make the point that any way of achieving a result is valid.We are all different and will never all reach the same goal in the same way.There is no 'textbook'. My pupils are given many, many strategies, in order that they find their own way. My ways are only best for ME.Although others may find mileage in them...

Comment: Well, if this technique worked fine, I doubt it would have been material for a question here. We make progress since we can use past experience. To throw that away and tell a beginner that "all techniques are good, bro" is not productive to me. Especially this technique which I can't see how it could work. If someone asks if he should start playing guitar with his hands or feet, the answer should be with the hands if they work, although a guitar has been played to good effect with the feet. "Whatever works for you is awesome" is not the best advice. Potentially better ways should be shown.